# Unable to update database query in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have to fetch the record from the form of an array. following is an array result.

```
Array(
    [price] => Array
    (
        [0] => 210
    )

    [code] => Array
    (
        [0] => SER-1001
    )
)
Array
(
    [price] => Array
    (
        [1] => 80
    )

    [code] => Array
    (
        [1] => XYZ-121
    )
)
```

Now I am confused, how to update that records in product table where a code is e.g. `SER-1001` in the database then the price should be updated `210`.

Same way as I do rest of matching code records.

Comment: updating multiple products at one time?

Comment: Yes... i get the updated price value along with product code.

Comment: using foreach loop show value in the form and then update

Comment: It will be good idea if you can generate or re-arrange array as 0,1,2... outer index and price, code as inner index

Comment: 2 ways, either loop over array (costly in terms of performance), or simplify array that you are getting from form.

Comment: @nadygold Please paste your code here

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
  $data = array(  
    'price'=> $value['price'];
  );  
  $this->db->where('code', $value['code']);  
  $this->db->update(‘database-table-name’,$data);   
}
```

try this, here you are looping through the array and updating the data one by one.

Comment: Message: Undefined index: price
same for code ... I think it should be loop

Answer (score 0):

```php
    $array = [
     [
        'price' => [ '0' => 210],
        'code' =>['0' => 'SER-1001']
    ],
    [
        'price' => ['1' => 80],
        'code' =>['1' => 'XYZ-121']
    ]
];
```

With reference to the above output array. You can write the code something like this.

```php
$counter = 0;
foreach($array as $data)
{
    if(isset($data['code'][$counter]))
    {
        $code = $data['code'][$counter];

        $data = [
            'price' => $data['price'][$counter];
        ];

        $this->db->where($column, $code);

        $this->db->update('database-table-name',$data);  
    }

    $counter++;
}
```

Comment: Ahsan Zameer When i tried above then i got error from controller before going to model. error is following
Message: A non-numeric value encountered

Comment: Can you tell me on which line error is showing? So I can edit my code accordingly

Comment: Actually before sending to model.. i have calculated some of values like following
$final['price'][$i]= ($data['results'][$i]->purchase_price + $_POST['price'][$i]);
 $final['code'][$i] = $_POST['code'][$i];
in this line => $final['price'][$i]... i get the error

Comment: Does `$data['results'][$i]->purchase_price` value has integer value?

Comment: after _print($data['results'][$i]->purchase_price); die;
string(3) "200"

Comment: Seems legit. Paste the whole controller function